# I have a json object now how do I make a div with the elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, getjson

I am using getJson to pull in some info onto the page

```
$('#request_song').autocomplete({
  serviceUrl: '<%= ajax_path("trackName") %>',
  minChars:1,
  width: 300,
  delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
  deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
  params: { artists: 'Yes' },
onSelect: function(value, data){
    // alert('You selected: ' + value + ', ' + $('#request_artist').val()); 
        $.getJSON('/get_events', function(data) {
                    $(data).each(function(key, value) {
                        console.log(value);
                    });
                });

    },
});
```

The json will have the name of the event and the city and date

I need to make a have a div that is on the page have the values from the json like

```
<div id="event_data">

//table info from json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your response looks something like this...

```
var data = [{
  "event": "Birthday"
  "name": "John Doe",
  "city": "Sunnyvale",
  "date": "04/07/1982"
},{
  ...
}]
```

If you use `$('<div />')` or `$('<div></div>')` to create new elements, jQuery will use regex before creating the element which for obvious reasons will slow you down if you're dealing with large data sets.

For performance use:

```
var div = $(document.createElement('div'));

or keep it simple...

var div = document.createElement('div');
```

For performance use standard for loop, not $.each, and cache the length:

```
var container = $("#event_data");

for(var i = 0, k = data.length; i < k; i++){
  var event = $(document.createElement('div')),
      name = $(document.createElement('span')),
      city = $(document.createElement('span')),
      date = $(document.createElement('span'));

  // add id to event wrapper, if undefined generate random ID to avoid conflicts
  event.attr('id', 'event_'+data[i].event || Math.floor(Math.random()*100));

  // add each item, if undefined then insert empty text
  name.text(data[i].name || "").appendTo(event);
  city.text(data[i].city || "").appendTo(event);
  date.text(data[i].date || "").appendTo(event);

  // append & appendTo do exactly the same thing, markup preference
  container.append(event);
}
```

If you use text() the value will be treated as just that, text only, and **will not** be executed. If you use html() **you'll have XSS issues**.

Hopefully this helps and is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Put markup in the argument to `$()` to create an element from it. Use values in a `{}` lookup to set attributes and text content (in jQuery 1.4). eg. something like:

```
$('#event_data').append(
    $('<div class="event"/>', {id: 'event_'+key}).append(
        $('<span class="event-name"/>', {text: value.name})
        $('<span class="event-city"/>', {text: value.city})
        $('<span class="event-date"/>', {text: value.date})
    )
);
```

Don't try to stick it together yourself (`$('<span>'+value.name+'</span>')`) or you'll have HTML-encoding issues and probably cross-site-scripting security holes.